# redirect url from htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to bulk redirect my site link like this,I need to remove home from every link and redirect it to root directory as shown below.

```
example.com/home/hello-world. 
example.com/home/tag/world.
```

to

```
example.com/hello-world
example.com/tag/world.
```

I'm using these code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/home(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You have a dot at the end of “some” of your example URLs - is that significant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that your htaccess rules file have more rules apart from your shown ones, which will take care of handling pages from backend(rewrite), if this is the case then please try following htaccess rules file.

Please these rules at top of your htaccess rules file. Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /example.com/
RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for helping me, 

its working but its redirecting to homepage only. I also tried putting rules on first line

What I need is -

example.com/home/hello-world TO example.com/hello-world.

I just need to remove /home/ part from every url.

Comment: @ajax, could you please do check my updated rules once and let me know if these help you? Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: Minor point, but the `RewriteBase` directive is not being used here. (However, it certainly shouldn't be set to `/example.com/` - which would appear to be the name of the domain, not a subdirectory.)

Comment: @MrWhite, In OP's comments I could see `example.com/home/hello-world` is written so I thought its a directory that's why I have set it like that. Please do let me know if this needs to be changed or so.

Comment: Well, it's not being used anyway in this example because of the slash prefix on the _substitution_ string in the `RewriteRule` that follows. (`RewriteBase` only applies to _relative_ substitutions.) So, if the code as written is working then it can't be a directory (because it's not being used).